# Set different background colors on the FilteringSelect options

Tags: combobox, dojo

I've got a FilteringSelect dijit working on a PHP project but I want to set some of the options to havea blue background and some other a red background. Can anyone please advise on hot to do this.

Thanks,
Arturo

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want to override FilteringSelect.labelFunc() to return an HTML snippet like

```
<span style="background-color: red>label</span>
```

Comment: That doesn't entirely works as when an option is selected, the text on the text box keeps the span tag instead of just displaying the label (eg. instead of having just "label" it has "<span style ...."

Comment: Ah, that's true, I think I just fixed that though, the first line changed in http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/changeset/22539 (but unfortunately that won't be available until the 1.6 release).